# How to push locally stored user actions ( page views, events etc.) to the Google analytics once user comes online for metro application?

Tags: c#, windows-8, google-analytics

I have integrated  [Google analytics SDK](https://googleanalyticssdk.codeplex.com/documentation) for window 8 and it's working as expected in online mode. 
But we have a scenario where user can use the application in offline mode and then he can switch back to online mode. 
So how can we record all the user actions in local store and push to GA once app is connected to internet ?

Thanks 
Mridul Saurabh Verma

Answer (score 0):

I think your looking for the [measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/)

> The Google Analytics Measurement Protocol allows developers to make
>   HTTP requests to send raw user interaction data directly to Google
>   Analytics servers.

If you save the info while they are offline then when they are online you can send it to GA. Only problem I can see is you cant send a date so if they are offline for a few days you are going to be uploading 2 days worth of data and it will only show the date that it was uploaded.

Comment: Thanks Dalmto, that's the only problem I am facing now. I have GA API's to push actions anytime. I have stored locally with date time stamp in offline mode but there is not API exists in GA Tracker which can pass the date time details so it's useless to push user actions of worth one day from all across world at one particular time. :( Can we use some workaround to overcome this problem ? I would appreciate if you can recommend other analytics tools other than GA which supports offline interactions for metro apps.

Comment: You could add a custom dimension with the ActualTime.  Not the best solution but I'm still thinking.   Daily Upload might be an option but I don't know enough about it i'm reading the documentation now.  Edit: Cost data upload doesn't let you upload dates either and its not for this anyway.